# Assigning variables of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, streamreader, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to assign variables(`var1-4`) for the four parts of my second(`lines2`) array.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string var1;
    string var2;
    string var3;
    string var4;

    string readContents;
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"File.txt"))
    {
        readContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        string[] lines = readContents.Split('\r');
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            string[] lines2 = s.Split('\t');
            foreach (string s2 in lines2)
            {
                var1 = lines2[0];
                var2 = lines2[1];
                var3 = lines2[2];
                var4 = lines2[3];
                Console.WriteLine(var4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, I am having an issue where `var1` returns the data I want, but the console is showing 8x more of the value than actually exists within my file. And I am always getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException` on every `var` after the first one during run-time. Not sure what is causing either of these errors.

EDIT: Data from text file - Each separated by a tab:

```
2015-04-19 00:00:00  HostName.ErrorLevel    IP Address  "Error Message"
2015-04-19 00:00:00  HostName.ErrorLevel    IP Address  "Error Message"
2015-04-19 00:00:01  HostName.ErrorLevel    IP Address  "Error Message"
```

Comment: Can you post the data in your text file so we can have a better idea what's going on?

Comment: You're `foreach`-ing through each `string` in `lines2` but never using `s2`.  This is why you're writing far too much to the console.  The exception is likely because there are less than 4 tab separated items on a line.  Stepping through this should make both problems obvious.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the first line and go debugging step by step, do you get the expected output on those 2 splits?

Comment: @CharlesMager got it. Change those `lines2[x]` to `s2[x]`

Comment: Error ended up being because my `"Error Message"`s have new lines within them as well, and that was throwing off the `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either iterate over results of `Split` and do something with each OR access results by index. Your code doing both and while have chance to be correct it will repeat assignment multiple times.

Additionally you are not checking for number of parts in the string and getting "index out of range" as result.

There is already method that reads all lines into enumerable - [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so the only thing left is to properly split each string:

```
    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
        string[] lines2 = s.Split('\t');
        if (lines2.Length == 4)
        {
          var1 = lines2[0];
          var2 = lines2[1];
          var3 = lines2[2];
          var4 = lines2[3];
          Console.WriteLine(var4);
        }
        else
        { 
             // report error?
        }
      }
    }
```